# Enantiomers or Diastereomers?

Tags: stereochemistry

The key tells me these are enantiomers.

[image]

I however don't think they are; their chiral carbons' configurations aren't inverted - i.e. only one chiral carbon's R/S configuration changes! This suggests diastereomers to me! Plus the Sawhorse projections I draw don't seem to be mirror images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are diastereomers.  Both of the "front" chiral carbons (the one with the bromine attached) are "S".  Rotate the one on the right 120 degrees CCW and it is identical to the one on the left.  But the "back" carbon (the one with the hydroxyl attached) is "S" on the left figure and "R" on the right figure - diastereomers.

Comment: I get the opposite of what you get for the back carbon for both images.

Comment: Are you "holding" the hydrogen such that the "steering wheel" is between your eye and the hydrogen?

Comment: I'm not holding the hydrogen; I'm holding the group with priority 2 and rotating the molecule so the hydrogen is pointing away. ETA: And so I am holding the hydrogen so that the steering wheel is between my eye in the hydrogen.

Comment: Try holding the lowest priority group, in this case hydrogen, so that the 3 remaining groups form a circle (steering wheel) between your eye and hand.  When you travel around the circle going from the highest priority group (1) to the next to lowest priority group (3) by way of (2), if you travel CW then your chiral center has the "R" configuration, if you travel CCW, then the "S" configuration.

Comment: I'm still traveling clockwise for the left figure. Will insert picture of model in OP.

Comment: The OH group has priority 1, the carbon chain priority 2, the methyl group priority 3, the hydrogen priority 4 - right?

Comment: Yep, got that. Model inserted.

Comment: what color ball represents what in your model?

Comment: Sorry, it's on the paper. Y is H, B is methyl, G is -OH, O is side chain.

Comment: Your model does not represent the Newman projection pictured at the very top-left of your post.  You need to swap the chain and the methyl.

Comment: What does that do? The order is still green --> orange --> blue.

Comment: If you swap groups 2 and 3 then the direction of travel (CW \ CCW) has to change.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now! How did I manage to build the model wrong and draw the Fischer projection incorrectly?

Comment: Great!  Glad to help.

Comment: Yes! I think I also figured out my Newman to Fischer woes - I have to eclipse the Newman before converting to Fischer. Guess I learn something everyday.